How to save relationship data manually in Laravel Filament V3?
I have two models Student and StudentFeePayment. They have one-to-one relationship as shown here:
// In Student model
public function studentFeePayment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StudentFeePayment::class);
}

// In StudentFeePayment model
public function student() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}

In the filament StudentResource file, I am trying to implement custom saving logic of the relationship studentFeePayment.
Fieldset::make('Payment')
    ->relationship('studentFeePayment')
    ->schema([ ...... ])

First I tried to implement inside getHeaderActions() inside ListStudent file but relationship items are not available, data only for the resource model (Student) are available. Is this a normal behaviour?
class ListStudents extends ListRecords
{
    protected static string $resource = StudentResource::class;
    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\CreateAction::make()->label('Register New Student')
                ->using(function (array $data, string $model): Model {
                    // Here $data does not contain relationship items
                })
        ];
    }
}

Next from this link I tried to implement using saveRelationshipsUsing()
Fieldset::make('Payment')
    ->relationship('studentFeePayment')
    ->schema([ .... ])
    ->saveRelationshipsUsing(function (Model $student, $state){
         // Custom code to save relationship data
         StudentService::createStudentFeePayment($student, $state);
     }) 

It works only for Create action if I set false to relationship() second parameter as below:
Fieldset::make('Payment')
    ->relationship('studentFeePayment', false)
    ->schema([ .... ])
    ->saveRelationshipsUsing(function (Model $student, $state){
         // Custom code to save relationship data
         StudentService::createStudentFeePayment($student, $state);
     }) 

For Edit/ Update action it does not works as it tried to delete the existing StudentFeePayment record. However, it works, if I remove the false setting in the relationship() 2nd parameter.
So it seems like I have to set false and true for Create and Update actions respectively.
So I want to know a consistent way to implement custom saving of relationship data in Laravel Filament.
Note: I use action modals for create and edit actions.

If you want to use the FieldSet to only add new records without affecting the current records, you can manipulate the relationship with a where clause that restricts the data from being deleted.
For example, in the Student Model, you can write:

    public function studentFeePayment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StudentFeePayment::class)
                   ->where('created_at', '>', now());
    }


